# TSQL Replicating LAG() function with dynamic offset

Tags: sql, t-sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to recreate the `LAG()` function without using `LAG()` but has a dynamic `Offset` that is dependent on a column.  I'm going to copy this code into `SparkSQL`.

Here is my sample data:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#myTable') is not null drop table #myTable
create table #myTable (id int,dates int, flag char, FromToFlagType varchar(2),FromToCounter INT)

insert into #myTable values(1,  '20181031','V','VV',1)
insert into #myTable values(2,  '20181130','V','VV',2)
insert into #myTable values(3,  '20181231','V','VV',3)
insert into #myTable values(4,  '20190131','F','VF',1)
insert into #myTable values(5,  '20190228','F','FF',2)
insert into #myTable values(6,  '20190331','F','FF',3)
insert into #myTable values(7,  '20190430','F','FF',4)
insert into #myTable values(8,  '20190531','V','FV',1)
insert into #myTable values(9,  '20190630','V','VV',2)
insert into #myTable values(10, '20190731','V','VV',3)

id  dates       flag    FromToFlagType  FromToCounter
1     20181031    V           VV                1
2     20181130    V           VV                2
3     20181231    V           VV                3
4     20190131    F           VF                1
5     20190228    F           FF                2
6     20190331    F           FF                3
7     20190430    F           FF                4
8     20190531    V           VF                1
9     20190630    V           VV                2
10  20190731      V           VV                3
```

So what I want to do is to replicate the following result, but without using a dynamic `Offset`:

```
select
  *
  ,LAG(FromToFlagType,FromToCounter-1) OVER ( ORDER BY dates) AS FromToStage
from 
  #mytable

id  dates     flag  FromToFlagType  FromToCounter   FromToStage
1     20181031  V             VV              1             VV
2     20181130  V             VV              2             VV
3     20181231  V             VV              3             VV
4     20190131  F             VF              1             VF
5     20190228  F             FF              2             VF
6     20190331  F             FF              3             VF
7     20190430  F             FF              4             VF
8     20190531  V             FV              1             FV
9     20190630  V             VV              2             FV
10  20190731    V             VV              3             FV
```

I know that you can replicate `LAG()` with `CTE` and `JOIN`, but it seems to only work if you know ahead of time what the offset is going to be. I've tried something similar here, but I'm just not able to get the same result.
I've found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438735/dynamic-variable-offset-in-sparksql-lead-lag-function), but I'm new to Spark and I need a solution what uses `SparkSQL`. I figured that if I can just replicate the function that I can copy it over to 'Spark'.

```
WITH FromToStage AS(
select 
    *
    ,id-(FromToCounter-1) AS id_2 
    from #mytable
   --order by dates
)
SELECT
  a.*
  ,b.FromToFlagType as FromToStage
FROM 
  FromToStage a
    JOIN
  FromToStage b
  ON
  a.id = b.id_2
order by dates
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `LAG` allows for *offset* to contain columns in its expression. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d857dafe705ca0674ef3d50d8f11e970).

Comment: If you *must* reinvent the wheel, use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE and a self join; but it'll be far less performant.

Comment: SparkSQL does not allow for dynamic offsets, it needs to be a literal. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html

I tried self joins, it seems to work as long as I know my offset ahead of time.

Comment: So, if your destination DBMS is a SQL Server instance, why not use a Stored Procedure instead? In T-SQL `LAG` has *always* supported a column to be part of the definition for *offset*.

Comment: I'm confused... are you trying to do it in Spark or SQL Server?

Comment: I didn't really wanted to bring Spark into the discussion, but it's just to explain why I need it. There are other reasons too, but effectively I'm looking to emulate the ability to do Offset in the LAG function using a column instead of a fixed number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logic, you want `first_value()`

```
select t.*,
       first_value(FromToFlagType) over (partition by seqnum - seqnum_2 order by date)_ as first_FromToFlagType
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by flag order by date) as seqnum_2
      from #mytable t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you! I realised I made a slight mistake in the input and output examples, but the solution works.